# How to Write Test Class for If Condition

Tags: trigger, unit-test

**How to Write Test Class for If Condition...**

[image]

This is my Trigger...

```
trigger TierPricingOffers on OpportunityLineItem (before Insert,before Update,before delete)
{
 if(trigger.isBefore)
    {
    Set<Id> pbeIds = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> proIds = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> priIds = new Set<Id>();
        if(Trigger.isInsert)
        {
            for (OpportunityLineItem opli : Trigger.new) 
            {
                pbeIds.add(opli.PricebookEntryId);
                proIds.add(opli.Product2Id);
            } 
        }
        
        if(Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isDelete) 
        {
            for (OpportunityLineItem oppli : Trigger.old) 
            {
                if(oppli.PricebookEntryId != null && oppli.Product2Id != null) 
                {
                pbeIds.add(oppli.PricebookEntryId);
                proIds.add(oppli.Product2Id);
                }
            }
        }
                List<PricebookEntry> PE = [Select Id, Product2Id, priceBook2Id From PricebookEntry where Id in :pbeIds]; 
                List<Pricebook2> PB=[SELECT Id,Name,(SELECT Price_Book__c,Product__c,To_Unit__c,From_Unit__c,Price__c FROM Tier_Pricings__r)FROM Pricebook2];
                List<Product2> PR=[SELECT Id,(SELECT Price_Book__c,Product__c,To_Unit__c,From_Unit__c,Price__c FROM Tier_Pricings__r) FROM Product2 where Id in :proIds];
                    if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate)
                    {
                        for(OpportunityLineItem PItem : trigger.new)
                        {
                            for(Product2 p : PR )
                            {
                                for(PricebookEntry l: PE)
                                {
                                    Decimal prdPrice;
                                    for(Pricebook2 d:PB)
                                    {
                                        for(Tier_Price__c c : d.Tier_Pricings__r)
                                        {
                                            prdPrice = c.Price__c;
                                            if(l.priceBook2Id == c.Price_Book__c && l.Product2Id == c.Product__c )
                                            {
                                             if (PItem.Quantity >= c.From_Unit__c && PItem.Quantity <= c.To_Unit__c)
                                                                    
                                                {
                                                    PItem.UnitPrice = prdPrice;
                                                 
                                                }
                                                    
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }  
                                }        
                            }
                        }
                    }
                
    }
}
```

This is my @test class

```
@isTest
public class Productiondate_test
{
static testmethod void TestProductiondate()
{
Account acc = new Account(
Name = 'Test Account');
insert acc;

//get standard pricebook
Pricebook2  standardPb = [select id, name, isActive from Pricebook2 where IsStandard = true limit 1];

Pricebook2 pbk1 = new Pricebook2 (
Name='Test Pricebook Entry 1',
 isActive=true);
insert pbk1;

Product2 prd1 = new Product2 (
Name='Test Product Entry 1',
productCode = 'ABC', 
isActive = true);
insert prd1;


PricebookEntry pbe1 = new PricebookEntry (
Product2ID=prd1.id,
Pricebook2ID=standardPb.id,
UnitPrice=50,
isActive=true);
insert pbe1;

Tier_Price__c TierPrice = new Tier_Price__c(
Price_Book__c = stdPriceBookEntry.Pricebook2Id,
Product__c = stdPriceBookEntry.Product2Id,
To_Unit__c = 1,
From_Unit__c =100,
Price__c = 120 );
insert TierPrice;

Opportunity opp1 = new Opportunity (
Name='Opp1',
CloseDate=Date.today(),
Pricebook2Id = pbe1.Pricebook2Id, 
AccountId = acc.id);
insert opp1;


OpportunityLineItem lineItem1 = new OpportunityLineItem (OpportunityID=opp1.id, PriceBookEntryID=pbe1.id, quantity=4, totalprice=200);
insert lineItem1;

Test.startTest();

TierPrice.Price__c =125;
update TierPrice;

System.assertEquals(TierPrice.Price__c = 125,oppLineItem.UnitPrice = 125 );
Test.stopTest();
   
}
}
```

Comment: I suggest that you use system.debug to see what gets saved to your PricebookEntry, Pricebook and Product variables after calling your soql query. There is a chance that these variables might be empty because no record was found after running your query. You can also try putting system.debug inside each for loop to see if the for loop did get run or not. Use system.debug for printing the value of the variables that you're comparing before your if statements would also help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Are you posting under more than one account? This code looks basically identical to code that has been posted by another user.

Comment: Regardless, you should refactor this code before you try to write tests; those `for` loops are disastrously inefficient and need to be replaced by Maps.